# Session handler class give "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: php, session

i am using session handler class as follows

**Session_Handler.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Session Handler License
 * ===========
 *
 * @author      
 * @copyright   
 * @link       
 * @version     1.0
 */
class sessionHandle {  
    // session-lifetime
    var $lifeTime;
    // mysql-handle
    var $dbHandle;
    var $is_debug = false;

    function open($savePath = '', $sessName = '') {
     global $server, $database, $user, $password;

       $this->lifeTime = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");
       $dbHandle    = @mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
       $dbSel       = @mysql_select_db($database,$dbHandle);

        if($this->is_debug)
        {
            if($dbHandle)
            $t = 'connected';
            else
            $t = 'not connected';

            $this->dataLog($server.','.$user.','.$password.','.$database.','.$t);
        }   

       // return success
       if(!$dbHandle || !$dbSel)
           return false;

       $this->dbHandle = $dbHandle;
       return true;
    }
    function close() {
        $this->gc(ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime'));
        return @mysql_close($this->dbHandle);
    }

    function read($sessID) {
        global $registry,$globalSettings;
        $query = "SELECT session_data AS d FROM `conf_event_data_log_session`
                            WHERE session_id = '$sessID'
                            AND session_expires > ".time();
       if($this->is_debug)
        {
            $this->dataLog($query);
        }                        
        $res = mysql_query($query, $this->dbHandle);

        // return data or an empty string at failure
        if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            if($this->is_debug)
            {
                $this->dataLog('DATA ->>>>>'."\n".$row['d']);
            }   
            return $row['d']; 
        }
        return "";
    }

    function write($sessID, $sessData) {

        // new session-expire-time
        global $registry, $globalSettings;

        $current_event = addslashes($_REQUEST['current_event']);
        $q = "SELECT * FROM conf_events WHERE url = '" . $current_event . "'";
         if($this->is_debug || true)
        {
            $this->dataLog($q);
        }
         $query                 = mysql_query($q);

        $current_event_id   = mysql_fetch_row($query);
         $event_id              = $current_event_id[0];
         //$sessData_new            =  $this->unserialize_php($sessData);
         $sessData_new          = $sessData_new['z93my8/SztfFxc/d0w=='];//attendee_data encoded array
         $attendee_id           = $sessData_new['attendee_id'];


         $browser_arr   = $this->getBrowser();
         $device_type   = 'Computer';
        //MOBILE DETECT
        $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
        if ($detect->isMobile() ||  $detect->isiOS() || $detect->isAndroidOS() || $detect->isTablet() ) 
        {
            if($detect->version('iPad'))
            {
                $device_type        = 'iPad';
                $browser_arr['platform']        = $detect->version('iPad');
            }
            if($detect->version('iPhone'))
            {
                $device_type        = 'iPhone';
                $browser_arr['platform']        = $detect->version('iPhone');
            }
            if($detect->version('Android'))
            {
                $device_type        = 'Android';
                $browser_arr['platform']        = $detect->version('Android');
            }

             if ($detect->version('Windows Phone')) {
                $device_type        = 'Windows Phone';
                $browser_arr['platform']        = $detect->version('Windows Phone');
            }

        }


        $newExp = time() + $this->lifeTime;
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `conf_event_data_log_session`  WHERE session_id = '$sessID'",$this->dbHandle);

        if(mysql_num_rows($res)) {
            $query = "UPDATE `conf_event_data_log_session`  SET session_expires = '$newExp', 
                            session_data = '".$sessData."',  event_id    ='$event_id',  attendee_id  ='$attendee_id',login_update    ='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', 
                            delete_test  ='".mysql_real_escape_string($current_event)."',ip_address = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->getClientIP())."',device_type = '$device_type',operating_system = '".mysql_real_escape_string($browser_arr['platform'])."' ,
                            browser_type = '".mysql_real_escape_string($browser_arr['name'])."',browser_version = '".mysql_real_escape_string($browser_arr['version'])."',user_agent='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])."' 
                         WHERE session_id = '$sessID'";
            if($this->is_debug)
            {
                $this->dataLog($query);
            }             
            mysql_query($query, $this->dbHandle);



            // if something happened, return true
            if(mysql_affected_rows($this->dbHandle))
                return true;
        }else {
            $query =  "INSERT INTO `conf_event_data_log_session` (session_id, session_expires, session_data, event_id, attendee_id, delete_test, login_time,ip_address,device_type,operating_system,
                        browser_type,browser_version,user_agent )
                         VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessID)."','$newExp','".$sessData."','$event_id','$attendee_id','".mysql_real_escape_string($current_event)."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','".mysql_real_escape_string($this->getClientIP())."','".mysql_real_escape_string($device_type)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($browser_arr['platform'])."',
                         '".mysql_real_escape_string($browser_arr['name'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($browser_arr['version'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])."')";
            if($this->is_debug)
            {
                $this->dataLog($query);
            }   

            mysql_query($query, $this->dbHandle);


            // if row was created, return true
            if(mysql_affected_rows($this->dbHandle))
                return true;
        }
        // an unknown error occured
        return false;
    }
    function destroy($sessID) {
        $query = "DELETE FROM `conf_event_data_log_session` WHERE session_id = '$sessID'";
        if($this->is_debug)
        {
            $this->dataLog($query);
        }
        mysql_query($query, $this->dbHandle);

       if(mysql_affected_rows($this->dbHandle))
            return true;

        // ...else return false
        return false;
    }
    function gc($sessMaxLifeTime) {
        // delete old sessions
        $query = "DELETE FROM `conf_event_data_log_session` WHERE session_expires < ".time();
       if($this->is_debug)
        {
            $this->dataLog($query);
        }
        mysql_query($query, $this->dbHandle);

        // return affected rows
        return mysql_affected_rows($this->dbHandle);
    }

    function unserialize_php($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
                throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
            }
            $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
            $num = $pos - $offset;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num + 1;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }
    function getClientIP() {
        if (isset($_SERVER)) {

           if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
               return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

           if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
               return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

           return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }

        if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
           return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
           return getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

        return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    }
    function getBrowser()
    {
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        //$u_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:10.0) like Gecko';//$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version= "";

        //First get the platform?
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "MSIE";
        }

        elseif(preg_match('/Trident\/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}; rv:([0-9]*)/',$u_agent,$matches_naeem))
        {
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "MSIE";
        }

        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
            $ub = "Firefox";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Google Chrome';
            $ub = "Chrome";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Safari';
            $ub = "Safari";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "Opera";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Netscape';
            $ub = "Netscape";
        }

        // finally get the correct version number
        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';

        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
            // we have no matching number just continue
        }

        // see how many we have
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1) {
            //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
            //see if version is before or after the name
            if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
                $version= $matches['version'][0];
            }
            else {
                $version= $matches['version'][1];
            }
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }

        // check if we have a number
        if ($version==null || $version=="") {

            if($matches_naeem[1])
                $version = $matches_naeem[1];
            else
                $version = "?";

        }

        return array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
        );
    }

    function dataLog($data)
    {
        $fhandle = fopen('session_log.txt','a+');
        fwrite($fhandle, $data."\n");
        fclose($fhandle);
    }
}

$session = new sessionHandle();
$session_status = session_set_save_handler(
                         array($session,"open"),
                         array($session,"close"),
                         array($session,"read"),
                         array($session,"write"),
                         array($session,"destroy"),
                         array($session,"gc"));
//session_write_close();
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
//session_start();
// etc...
?>
```

now it is showing error message "The page isn't redirecting properly" after couple of days or month.

**index.php file**

```
require_once('WABRegistry/helpers/Session_Handler.php');
session_start();
```

it works OK but after couple of days or month we have to ask support person to restart apache and it resolved our issue but this time it is didn't work same error can you please help

**EDITED:** 
it is not coming in the  `function write($sessID,$sessData) {`

Comment: You might get better luck with this one on Superuser. If the code works for a while, then a restart normally solves the issue - it's not really in the code, but sounds like a problem with the server.

Comment: but now support has restarted server and it still their

Comment: I cannot see any redirection in the code either. You could try to use the webmaster tools of browser and check what is redirecting where. It should be on an endless loop.

Comment: when any error come it starting show me redirection error message

Comment: If you remove error suppressing from mysql_connect and mysql_close and mysql_select_db, you'll get your answer.

Comment: nothing, same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my fault i was using `$sessData_new['z93my8/SztfFxc/d0w=='];` when i changed it to `$_SESSION['z93my8/SztfFxc/d0w=='];` it start working

i also get to know that the write function of session handler didn't write a file it can store values in the database